# Does 1-NN classifier approaches 0?

Tags: classification

Does the training error rate of a 1-NN classifier approaches 0 with the number of training data points approaches infinity?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to approach infinity. Imagine that your training set is a single sample, the nearest neighbor to the single sample is the sample itself, *voila* you achieved perfect training error. If the samples are distinct from each other, i.e. there are no two identical feature vectors pointing to the different target variable, then you would always achieve perfect error since the nearest neighbor would be always the sample itself. If you have the same different feature vectors pointing to different targets, then the error would be non-zero and would depend on what exactly your data is, more specifically the noise distribution.

Comment: Thank you! What about the out-of-sample error?

Comment: @stateNeth that's a different question. Moreover, I guess that you would like a formal proof for that, so I'd encourage you to ask it as a separate question.